# Predictive coding without using loops in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, compression

I have a set of numbers and I want to use predictive coding to get smaller values for this set of data as each value should not differ to much from the last.  I was just starting very simply with a expected value that each value would be the same as the last, and then just store the error.

For some simple data:

```
1 2 -3 1
```

The values I should get are

```
1 1 -5 4
```

The way I was doing this compression was one line, but to decompress I need the last value, so I put this in a loop.  Is there a way to do this, and possibly more complex(looking at more the just the last value) predictive coding without needing to use Matlab loops.

Comment: Think you are looking for `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Divakar, constructing the new values can be done by

```
B = [A(1) diff(A)];
```

Obtaining the original from this result, the inverse of the above procedure, is done through

```
A = cumsum(B);
```

Comment: I was considering that. For more complex functions, I don't think those have such a simple solution. Do you know what solutions might also work with linear predictive coding?

Comment: I would take a look at [`lpc`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/signal/ref/lpc.html). I have to admit that I actually dont know what you mean by decompression. I put the inverse approach in my answer, but I am not aware of the existence of this kind of procedures for linear predictive coding.

Comment: I can decently believe that I am just getting confused.  The page helped though, even if its not exactly what I am looking for